# get_absolute_url not making any effect

Tags: python, django, django-templates

I only used this in my template. I am following a tutorial. In tutorial video is working but I couldn't make it work. Here is my template code:

```
<i>     {% for object in object_list %}
    <div class="media">
        <div class="media-left">
            <a href="#">
                {% if object.img %} <img class="media-object" src="..." alt="...">
                {% endif %}
            </a>
        </div>
        <div class="media-body">
            {{ object.content }}<br/>
            via {{ object.user }} | {{ object.timestamp|timesince }} ago |
            <a href='{{ object.get_absolute_url }}'>View</a>
        </div>
    </div>
    <hr/> </i>
```

My views.py

```
<i>
```

Create your views here.

```
class TweetCreateView(FormUserNeededMixin, CreateView):
    form_class = TweetModelForm
    template_name = 'tweets/create_view.html'



class TweetUpdateView(LoginRequiredMixin, UserOwnerMixin, UpdateView):
    form_class = TweetModelForm
    queryset = Tweet.objects.all()
    template_name = 'tweets/update_view.html'
    success_url = '/tweets/'


class TweetDeleteView(LoginRequiredMixin, DeleteView):
    model = Tweet
    template_name = 'tweets/delete_confirm.html'
    success_url = reverse_lazy('tweets:home')


class TweetDetailView(DetailView):
    template_name = "tweets/detail_view.html"
    queryset = Tweet.objects.all()

    def get_object(self):
        print(self.kwargs)
        pk = self.kwargs.get("pk")
        print(pk)
        return Tweet.objects.get(id=pk)


class TweetListView(ListView):
    template_name = "tweets/tweets_list.html"


    def get_queryset(self, *args, **kwargs):
        qs = Tweet.objects.all()
        print(self.request.GET)
        query = self.request.GET.get("q", None)
        if query is not None:
            qs = qs.filter(Q(content=query))
        return qs

    def get_context_data(self, *args, **kwargs):
        context = super(TweetListView, self).get_context_data(*args, **kwargs)
        context['create_form'] = TweetModelForm()
        context['create_url'] = reverse_lazy('tweets:create')
        return context


</i>
```

my models.py

```
<i>

class Tweet(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, )
    content = models.CharField(max_length=140, validators=[ validate_content ])
    updated = models.DateField(auto_now=True, )
    timestamp = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True, )

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.content)
</i>
```

Comment: is that the instance property`get_absolute_url` exists?

Comment: I am just biginer. What does instance method mean? I used get_absolute_url only in template.

Comment: post the corresponding view, model

Comment: Did you define get_absolute_url() in the model? If not, how do you expect it to work?

Comment: I tried that before but it didn't work. I already explained I am following a video tutorial.

Comment: The point is I wanted to view a post in detail. Just like in twitter or any other site, when you click on 'view' button it should show in detail.

Comment: It sounds like you need a better tutorial.

Comment: thanks for your comment. It worked from the answer provided in answer section.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to add methode get_absolute_url to your models, it's should look like that :

```
def get_absolute_url(self):
    from django.urls import reverse
    return reverse('tweets:detail', kwargs={
        'pk': self.pk
    })
```

Comment: NoReverseMatch at /

u'tweet' is not a registered namespace this error detected now